# Sacar en pantalla resultado de un If else

Tags: javascript

Estoy realizando un código que tiene que hacer la condición de que si ingresas una menor cantidad de caracteres en el prompt, te envía nuevamente un prompt con un mensaje volviendo a pedir que ingreses una cantidad mayor de palabras , pero al realizar este ejercicio , el resultado de ingresar la cantidad correcta de palabras, no se esta mostrando en el documento, se muestra como una alerta con las palabras dentro de ella.

como puedo hacer para solucionar este error y me muestre bien en pantalla lo que esta en el ELSE.

```js
   function solicita(){
      // solicita el ingreso de una o mas palabras.
      var pregunta = prompt('Ingrese unas palabras');
      // Convierte cadenas en una Matriz a partir de el separador.
      var cantidadPalabras = pregunta.split(" ").length;
     // Respuesta condicional
        if(cantidadPalabras < 10){
            alert(prompt('Debes ingresar una cantidad mayor de palabras'));
        }else{
           document.write("<p> La cantidad de palabras son :" + cantidadPalabras + "</p>");
        }
    
    }
    
     solicita();
```

Comment: No entiendo, ¿entonces lo que buscas es como mostrar el resultado dentro de tu documento HTML?

Comment: Aunque `document.write` no es ni de cerca la mejor opción para lo que intentas, el código funciona y si muestra el contenido del `else` dentro del documento

Comment: El resultado lo esta mostrando en una ventana de alert, aunque tenga puesto el document.write en la "condicional else".

Comment: No, deberías checar de nuevo tu código por que si yo lo uso y meto 11 palabras, procede el contenido del else y si lo pinta en pantalla

Comment: Ya edité tu pregunta y puse tu script como ejecutable, comprueba tu mismo lo que te digo

Comment: @SebaLagos pero el mensaje está saliendo en un `alert` porque lo tienes puesto dentro en el if. Si no quieres que salga pon `document.getElementById('#id-del-elemento').innerHTML = "Debes ingresar una cantidad mayor de palabras"`. No sé si esto ayuda, pero si no, no estoy entiendo realmente que se quiere que haga

Comment: Esto es lo que tengo hacer  : Utilizando una ventana de prompt() solicitar un texto y contar la cantidad de palabras que lo componen. Si es menor a 10 palabras, alertar que son muy pocas y volver a solicitar un texto. Si es mayor, escribir en el documento las palabras por separado que componen el texto y contar sus caracteres.

Comment: @SebaLagos eso no es lo que pides en la pregunta, deberías ser mas claro por favor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prueba esto a ver:

```js
function solicita(){
      // solicita el ingreso de una o mas palabras.
      var pregunta = prompt('Ingrese unas palabras');
      // Convierte cadenas en una Matriz a partir de el separador.
      var cantidadPalabras = pregunta.split(" ").length;
     // Respuesta condicional
        if(cantidadPalabras < 10){
            document.write("<p> La cantidad de palabras son :" + volverSolicitar() + "</p>");
        }else{
           document.write("<p> La cantidad de palabras son :" + cantidadPalabras + "</p>");
        }
    
    }
    
    function volverSolicitar() {
      var texto = prompt('Debes ingresar una cantidad mayor de palabras');
      var numeroPalabras = texto.split(" ").length;
      if(numeroPalabras < 10){
            return document.write(volverSolicitar());
        }else{
           return numeroPalabras;
        }
    }
    
     solicita();
```

Comment: Claro, es algo asi... solo que en el return texto , deberia imprimir en pantalla la cantidad de caracteres y la cantidad de palabras .

Comment: Cierto, acabo de editarlo

Answer (score 0):

Así:

```js
function solicita(){
  // solicita el ingreso de una o mas palabras.
  var pregunta = prompt('Ingrese unas palabras');
  // Convierte cadenas en una Matriz a partir de el separador.
  var cantidadPalabras = pregunta.split(" ").length;
 // Respuesta condicional
    if(cantidadPalabras < 10){
        alert(prompt('Debes ingresar una cantidad mayor de palabras'));
    }else{
       document.getElementById('p').innerHTML = `<p> La cantidad de palabras son :  ${cantidadPalabras} </p>`
    }

}

 solicita();
```

```html
<p id="p"></p>
```

Lo que estamos haciendo es obtener el parrafo que insertamos y ponerle ese HTML y, al contenido del HTML estar con ``, es mucho más fácil.

Documentación: [Plantillas de texto (``)](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/template_strings)

Answer (score -1):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Intenta esto. Ojalá te sirva y editalo conforme a tus necesidades, saludos